# HL2 Crashes when i open a map

Tags: technical-issues, half-life-2

I bought the orange box(yes, they still sell it). I turned on the console with`-console` and entered`map push_pro` it loads the map but when I press w *hl2.exe* crashes!

What is going wrong?

Comment: try changelevel instead of map, if it goes on, try verifying game cache through Steam. As I assume the game is installed on steam.

Comment: @WizLiz You should have put that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***map*** is a command for changing map server side and is thus not suited for client side game (like Half-Life 2). Use ***changelevel*** instead.

If the issue persist, verify game cache through Steam (if I'm not mistaken HL2 is always installed on Steam)

Comment: Yep. I bought a retail disk and it wanted steam!